# How to reload a static hashMap in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I wonder if it's possible to "reload" a hashmap after it has been changed.
Let's say i have this class:

```
public class CountryCultures {

static final EnumMap<Country, Culture> countriesMap;

static {
 
countriesMap = new EnumMap<>(Country.class);

//Culture class has a single string attribute to set the language
Culture spanishCulture = new Culture ("Spanish")

countriesMap.put(Country.Spain, spanishCulture);

Culture englishCulture = new Culture ("English")

countriesMap.put(Country.England, englishCulture);

}

}
```

So then i access that map and modify it:

```
CountryCultures.countriesMap.get(Country.Spain).setCultureLanguage("Catalonian");
```

After i modify and use the map with the changes i would like to reset it to the original value given in the CountryCultures class. Something like:

```
CountryCultures.countriesMap.reload;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just create a static method that clears and then refills the Map with whatever you consider it's "original" values. Then call said method when you feel like it.

Comment: This is just a little example of the real class. Real class has so many objects inside. It would mean to create a refill method which would repeat the same creation objects code, that's why i'm trying to reuse this same code from the original class.

Comment: This isn't actually about the state of your map but more about the state of the *items* inside your map. Maybe you can add a `reload` or `reset` method in your `Culture` class that handles the logic. Then you can call `CountryCultures.countriesMap.get(Country.Spain).reload()` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Define the static initialization as calling the reload method and invoke it from the static block.

```
public class CountryCultures {
  private static Map<Country,Culture> countriesMap;

  static {
    countriesMap = new HashMap<>;
    reload();
  }

  public static void reload() {
    countriesMap.clear();
    ... populate with baseline mappings ...
  }
}
```